# How to read geometry data type from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, geometry, polygon

I have a table in MySQL that stores polygons. I can read this back on the command line using the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT polygonid, AsText(thepolygon) FROM polygons;
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | polygonid | AsText(thepolygon) |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | 1 | POLYGON((36.96318 127.002881,37.96318 127.002881,37.96318
128.002881,36.96318 128.002881,36.96318 127.002881)) | +-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 1 row in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
```

When I try to read this in PHP using the same query, polygonid comes back correctly, but thepolygon comes back as empty:

```
$query = "SELECT polygonid, AsText(thepolygon) FROM polygons";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    var_dump($row['polygonid']);
    var_dump($row['thepolygon']);

    [...]
```

results in

```
string(1) "1" NULL
```

meaning that 'thepolygon' comes back as NULL, but the 'polygonid' comes back just fine.

If I change the query to

```
SELECT polygonid, thepolygon FROM polygons
```

then I do get back binary data:

```
string(1) "1" string(97)
"�t{I{B@�1�3/�_@�t{I�B@�1�3/�_@�t{I�B@��`@�t{I{B@��`@�t{I{B@�1�3/�_@"
string
```

It's almost as if astext() does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any input at all!

Comment: FYI if you need to show properly formatted code on StackOverflow, add [four spaces before each line](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Using `>` for each line formats your text as a block quote, which will not preserve line breaks and spacing, so the code is difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it might just be because you've not given the `AsText()` selection an alias which can be picked up from the PHP array.

If you print out `$row` you might be able to see that your array does not have a `thepolygon` key.

Have you tried this?

```
$query = "SELECT polygonid, AsText(thepolygon) AS thepolygon FROM polygons";
```

It works on the command line because you're just printing out whatever is selected in the query, but in PHP you're trying to print out array keys - i.e. the name of the fields selected. Your MySQL query does not select a field called `thepolygon`, so it doesn't exist in the array either.

Comment: And that solved it! Thanks a lot. It is much appreciated!

Comment: oops. sorry about that. still new at this :P